# Carrierwave Upload with Amazon S3 - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am attempting to use Carrierwave with Amazon S3 in my Rails app, and I keep getting the error

```
"Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)."  
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

I also receive the warning

```
"[WARNING] fog: the specified s3 bucket name() is not a valid dns name, which will negatively impact performance.  For details see: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html"
```

**config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'AWS',                      
    aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"]
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV["AWS_BUCKET"]                
end
```

My bucket name is "buildinprogress"

I've double checked that my access key ID and access key are correct.

How can I fix this error??

Comment: I'm finding that if I hardcode the bucket name in my carrierewave.rb file, it works, but when I have the bucket name defined as an environment variable, it doesn't work.

Comment: That can't be; you probably messed up something with the ENV variables then. Do a `puts ENV["AWS_BUCKET"].inspect` in the initializer file and check that the correct bucket name is printed...

Answer (score 6):

It is a problem with Fog/Excom that kept throwing random errors for me too.

My fix was to remove **gem 'fog'** and replace it with **gem 'carrierwave-aws'** instead.

Then, in your ***_uploader.rb** change

```
storage :fog ---> storage :aws
```

and update your **carrierwave.rb** file Ex.:

```
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage    =  :aws                  # required
    config.aws_bucket =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']      # required
    config.aws_acl    =  :public_read

    config.aws_credentials = {
      access_key_id:      ENV['S3_KEY'],       # required
      secret_access_key:  ENV['S3_SECRET']     # required
    }

    config.aws_attributes = {
                              'Cache-Control'=>"max-age=#{365.day.to_i}",
                              'Expires'=>'Tue, 29 Dec 2015 23:23:23 GMT'
                            }
  end
```

For more info check out the [carrierwave-aws](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws) GitHub page

Comment: Been having trouble with the fog gem for DAYS! Thank you so much, this worked! (had to change config.aws_acl to 'private' in my case, though, copied from the GitHub documentation)